# C#.net text filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, shortcode

I want to filter my text to a particular format.
Suppose i have a text like

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, `[iframe width="200" height="300"][/iframe]`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,

Which i want to convert like :

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
`< iframe width="200" height="300"></iframe >`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,

Ex2 : `[caption]My Caption[/caption]` will show  `<span class="caption">My Caption</span>`

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use an existing formatting language? Like Markdown, or BBCode

Comment: Wooooooooooooooow, I spent days writing an answer to a totally different question. Please format your questions correctly!!

Comment: didn't you understand my question i want to use this text paring like wordpress short code in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to parse your content and replace pre-defined "combinations" with html equivalent.

Also you'd need to be very carefull if you accept content from members since you'll be directly changing the html code with the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

James Deville has a very good question - likely the best solution is to use a text markup system that has been already put together (markdown, etc.).

But if you decide you *do* need to do this in a custom way (assuming there will be user input):

Just make sure to **NOT** use anything like `s/\[/</` and `s/\]/>/`. This will leave you wide open to vulnerabilities.

Someone could enter

```
[script type="text/javascript" src="http://malicious-server.haxx/XSS.js"]
```

which would be translated into

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malicious-server.haxx/XSS.js">
```

Then anyone viewing that fragment of text would also be requesting that malicious javascript unintentionally.

**Summary:** If you do this wrong you can introduce serious security vulnerabilities into your site. So use an already-implemented system if at all possible. Otherwise be very selective about what tags you accept.

Comment: i want this to parse in asp.net not javascript

Comment: I think you need to read my answer more carefully. It had nothing to do with parsing using javascript.

Comment: it will not parge all the text in to attribute i will parge only the method which i mention